# Have 4.3 SDK only, want 3.x as well

Tags: ios, sdk, versions

I know this has been discussed before, but I didn't quote understand most of the answers.  As you can tell from my other questions on here, I'm a complete newbie when it comes to app creation using XCode.  I only have the SDK for iOS 4.3.

A friend of mine wants my app, but he only has an iPhone 3.  He has not upgraded to iOS4.  I don't see any reason my app couldn't run at a lower iOS version, it's pretty simple.

So what I'd like to know is how can I add previous SDKs to my XCode library?  Do I just download a previous version of XCode w/ it's SDK and install that?  Will that brick XCode?  If so, what then?  Is there anything I can do, I'd really like this to be written with 3.x and above in mind.

The most simple and more straight forward answers without jargon will be extremely appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264894/which-version-of-the-ios-sdk-should-i-use

Answer (score 2):

if you have the iOS 4.3 SDK, you also can target any iOS version preceding it. In your Xcode project build settings, make sure your base SDK is set to the highest you have (in this case 4.3) but change your deployment target to whatever iOS version you want (try not to go lower than 3.0).

Make sure you test it though, to be sure that you are not using any features that are not present in the SDK version you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

Each download of the iOS contains each (most) of the previous versions.  They're in installer bundles in a folder on the disk image.  For example in the **xcode_4.0.1_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg**, (after you have installed the main package) open the **Packages** folder, install the **iPhoneSDK3_2.pkg**, and **iPhoneSimulatorSDK3_2.pkg** (if needed).